# Are there any best practices for folder structure with Harp.js and GitHub pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-pages, harp

I'm using [Harp](http://harpjs.com) to create a static website that shall be hosted on GitHub pages. So far, everything works, but I'm a little bit concerned about the folder structure.

This is because GitHub pages expects the files that shall be delivered in the root folder of the repository.

So I ended up with the current structure:

```
/
  .gitignore
  index.html
  _sources/
    harp.json
    README.md
    public/
      index.ejs
```

What bothers me is that I can not have the `README.md` file on top-level (which means that when going to the repository on GitHub, I am always told that I should create one, and that I need to step down one level manually), if I do not want the README.md to be public via GitHub pages as well.

Additionally, the build step feels strange. From within the `_sources` folder I need to run:

```
$ harp compile --output ..
```

This somehow feels wrong, compiling something and putting the result in the parent folder. It's a theoretical question, but if there was a `_sources` folder within the `public` folder, I'd end up with a big ball of mud :-/

Is there any way of how to structure this so that I can have everything in the `_sources` folder on top-level, while still being able to serve everything as it now is from GitHub pages?

Comment: there's a writeup here under 'publishing to production' https://github.com/openoakland/openbudgetoakland/tree/master

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a great solution for this with the fantastic [gh-pages](https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages) npm module.  Here is my setup:

Relevant dirs/files:

```
README.md
bin/
    publish
dist/
node_modules/
package.json
src/
    _layout.jade
    index.md
```

Relevant lines of `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "compile": "harp compile src dist",
  "publish": "npm run compile && bin/publish"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "coffee-script": "^1.9.2",
  "gh-pages": "^0.2.0",
  "harp": "^0.13.0"
},
```

Contents of `bin/publish` (this is coffeescript, but you can easily [convert it to JS](http://js2.coffee/)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee

ghpages = require 'gh-pages'
path = require 'path'

handle_error = (error) ->
  if error
    console.error error
    process.exit error.code or 1

dist = path.join __dirname, '..', 'dist'

ghpages.publish dist, handle_error
```

To publish, I simply run:

`npm run publish`

and it creates the gh-pages branch with the contents of the `dist` dir as the root of the repo, and pushes it to github!

In more detail, from the `gh-pages` docs:

> Calling this function will create a temporary clone of the current repository, create a `gh-pages` branch if one doesn't already exist, copy over all files from the base path, or only those that match patterns from the optional `src` configuration, commit all changes, and push to the `origin` remote.

This works like a charm for me.  Hope it helps others!

For a full working example, [here is a live example repo](https://github.com/decentralizedstack/website/tree/4e8c83b7374eda0121e6972f37176f279c7f6346) using all of the configuration described above (and more).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's not much you can do to get around the fact that Github pages requires static files in the root directory, and the fact that Harp clears the target directory on `compile`. It may feel counterintuitive, but storing your root files in a directory like _sources with the compiled files in root is still the prescribed method for this workflow. Additionally, while `harp compile` clears out the target directory, you can still keep files like your README in the root *if* you don't compile on that branch. You can keep your `master` branch clean and then only compile in `gh-pages` to 'deploy'.

Check out our current process at https://github.com/openoakland/openbudgetoakland/tree/master. I'd still like to find a less 'hacky' way to accomplish this myself, but this is what works for now.

Comment: This is mostly correct though harp does not clear out your source when you compile back one dir. Here is the source that handles that logic https://github.com/sintaxi/harp/blob/master/lib/helpers.js#L237-L266

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize my workflow for deploying to [User / Organization](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/) pages in [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) using [Harp](https://github.com/sintaxi/harp) and hopefully help someone out there.

My project before compiling.

[image: Directory before compiling.]

- `_deploy` is a simple shell script to take care of compiling, moving the README and pushing to Github.

```shell
# change dirs to _src if not already in there
if [ ${PWD##*/} != "_src" ]; then
  cd _src
fi

# source is the current directory and the target the parent directory
harp compile ./ ../

# files starting with _ are not copied to target. copy _README and rename
cp _README.md ../
cd ..
mv _README.md README.md

# commit to the repo and push to github 
git add .
git commit -m "Deploy."
git push
```

After compiling.

[image: Directory after compiling]

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bucaran/c8d8395d74975f9ab47f) for more.